# Mapping Composite primary keys of one table with that of the other table in ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework

I have a situation where I have an Entity named User and another Entity UserHasFriends and there is a many-to-many relationship between the two. For Instance, a user can be friends with many other users and vice versa. I have 2 Primary Keys in the User table, userId and another is uniqueNo, that is associated with the User. In the table UserHasFriends, I have composite primary key(userId, uniqueNo),which are also foreign keys to the User table, that indicates that the user is friends with other users. The table UserHasFriends also contains some other attributes.

The problem is: When i am trying to create this schema, it shows me an error: "Cannot add Foreign Key".

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`User` (
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `uniqueNo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phoneNo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`, `uniqueNo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`UserHasFriends` (
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `uniqueNo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `requestStatus` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`, `uniqueNo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: What code are you trying?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/as4iwkc6erl4h2i/mySchema.png @juergen d

Comment: You don't have two primary keys in the user table. A user table can only have one primary key. Please include your code directly in the question.

Comment: @OllieJones : Here is the code